# Why is the onclick event on the body element not working?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm trying to send users to another page when click html body:

JavaScript `c.js`:

```js
function clickBody(){
    window.location.href = '/';
}
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="c.js"></script>
</head>

<body onclick="clickBody();" />

</html>
```

I can run the function from console, but clicking the `<body>` is not working.

Comment: Add a `height:500px;` to the body, it then should work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `<body>` element has no height. Add something like the code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      height: 500px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="c.js"></script>
</head>

<body onclick="clickBody();/>  

</html>
```

Answer (score 22):

The `<body>` element is empty. You have to either change its height in CSS, or put some text in it.

Also, using `element.addEventListener()` might be a good idea. See [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35093997/3853934).

See code snippet:

```js
function clickBody() {
    window.location.href = '/'
}
document.body.addEventListener("click", clickBody)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="c.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Try clicking me.</p>
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I use window instead of document.body

```js
window.onclick = () => {
console.log('Page clicked')
}
```

```html
<h1>click anywhere on this page</h1>
```